# Why isn't my hook_theme being called or rendering output?

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to use the hook_theme function to utilize some template files.  I have the following function defined in my theme:

### template.php

```
function my_name_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
        'testy' => array(
            'variables' => array('title' => NULL),
            'template'  => 'testy',
        ),
    );
}
```

And I have the following template defined:

### testy.tpl.php

```
<h1><?php print $title; ?></h1>
```

I have a content type called "Page" with a corresponding template:

### node--page.tpl.php

```
<?php
    print 'before theme call';
    $variables = array();
    $variables['title'] = 'my title';
    print theme('testy', $variables);
    print 'after theme call';
?>
```

When viewing one of my "Page" content types, the rendered page only shows the following, with no title:

before theme callafter theme call

I have cleared all caches.  Why isn't this working?

Comment: Obvious question first: did you clear Drupal's caches?

Comment: @Clive Yes, I have.

Comment: see if Drupal includes your testy.tpl.php file first (put some garbage in PHP tag and see if you get a fatal error)

Comment: @AyeshK That's a good tip--I tried that and I am not getting any errors.  So, why isn't the template being loaded?

Comment: where did you put the test.tpl.php file ?

Comment: @AyeshK In my theme directory sites/all/themes/my_name/templates/testy.tpl.php

Comment: try the same folder as the module that hooks theme.

Comment: @AyeshK You mean where template.php is?  I tried that and cleared caches--no change.

Comment: @AyeshK I added a path, and now it works. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: great to hear that! Wish you all the best!

Comment: @AyeshK Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a `path` to my function, then it worked.

### template.php

```
function my_name_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
        'testy' => array(
            'variables' => array('title' => NULL),
            'template'  => 'testy',
            'path'      => drupal_get_path('theme', 'my_name') . '/templates',
        ),
    );
}
```